# How to convert LUA Table to matlab MAT File?

Tags: matlab, lua, machine-learning, torch

I want to save a LUA table as a MAT file. Structure of Table is as follows:

```
{
  1 : 
    {
      bounding_box : 
        {
          1 : 0.5
          2 : 0.5
          3 : 704.5
          4 : 1280.5
        }
      PatchName : "03952.jpg"
      confidence : 
        {
          1 : 0.99999818651222
          2 : 1.8134877758073e-06
        }
    }
  2 : 
    {
      bounding_box : 
        {
          1 : 45.5
          2 : 159.5
          3 : 132.5
          4 : 216.5
        }
      PatchName : "03953.jpg"
      confidence : 
        {
          1 : 0.99999864618192
          2 : 1.3538180818906e-06
        }
    }
 }
```

Can anybody guide me how to do that ?

I tried matio.save(string of path, table to save) but it returned following error:

```
bad argument #1 to 'varCreate' (cannot convert 'number' to 'const char *')
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'varCreate'
    /home/khurram/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/matio/init.lua:136: in function '__make_var'
    /home/khurram/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/matio/init.lua:78: in function '__make_var'
    /home/khurram/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/matio/init.lua:78: in function '__make_var'
    /home/khurram/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/matio/init.lua:434: in function 'save'
    main.lua:171: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    [string "_RESULT={dofile('main.lua')}"]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/khurram/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:651: in function </home/khurram/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:560>
    [string "require('trepl')()"]:1: in main chunk
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install and use https://github.com/soumith/matio-ffi.torch, e.g.:

```
local matio = require "matio"
matio.save("archive.mat",{foo="bar", scm="git"})
```

Comment: It works fine for simple tables. E.g. a table containing numbers as 2D structure. However if the structure of table is a little bit complex like 'structs' in matlab, this method gives error.

Comment: Only string keys are supported for tables and nested tables, which is why you encounter an error if you try to do e.g.: `matio.save("archive.mat",{"foo", "bar", "baz"})`